# Mocking callable objects using Mockito for Python

Tags: python, mockito, pytest

I have a function of the form:

```
def my_function(arg):
    f = get_anonymous_function(arg)
    return f()
```

I want to test this function in `mockito` with `py.test`.

So I write my test as follows:

```
def test_my_function(when):
    arg = mock()
    f = mock()
    when(my_module).get_anonymous_function(arg).thenReturn(f)

    expected = mock()
    when(f).thenReturn(expected)

    actual = my_module.my_function(arg)
    assert expected == actual
```

When I run such a test, `actual` is `None`. If I change `when` to `when2`, Mockito complains `TypeError: can't guess origin of 'f'.`

My provisional solution is to use `f = lambda: return expected`, and then skip the second `when`. This works, but feels not quite right. Is there a better way?

PS: "Don't use Mockito" is not really the answer I'm looking for. Likewise, "write `my_function` better" is not an option, as this sort of situation arises routinely when using external packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. From the [documentation](http://mockito-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/the-functions.html) (with typo corrected):

> Mocks are by default callable. Configure the callable behavior using
>   when:
>
> ```
> dummy = mock()
> when(dummy).__call__(1).thenReturn(2)
> ```